# Problem in Android in app billing using reserved product IDs

Tags: android, android-emulator, in-app-purchase, android-manifest

I am trying to run the sample billing app with reserved product IDs. I am able to get response only for `android.test.item_unavailable` but not for remaining IDs like `android.test.purchased`, `android.test.canceled`. I am running android 2.1 and Market version is showing as 2002306.

Please, help me.

Comment: do you have some success ??? please tell me I am also having same trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after upgrading my device to android 2.2, and market version 2.3.6